# Exibir dados em tabela PHP

Tags: php, aplicação-web, firebird

estou fazendo um relatório de vendas e preciso organizar os dados vindos de um banco em firebird fazer um relatório em `PHP`, porem nao estou conseguindo sabe quantos dados estao vindos do banco. Pois a função `ibase_num_fields` nao retorna quantos sao os dados. E depois como faria a organização desses dados em tabela ?

```
   $host='localhost:C:/bd_relatorio/clipp.FDB';    

   $dbh=ibase_connect($host,'SYSDBA','masterkey');

   $stmt = 'SELECT NOME FROM TB_CLIENTE';

   $sth = ibase_query($dbh, $stmt);   

   $total = ibase_num_fields($sth);

   if($total > 2){

     while ($row = ibase_fetch_row($sth)) {
         echo $row[0], "\n";
     }
   }
   echo $total;
   ibase_free_result($sth);
   ibase_close($dbh);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe nenhuma função na biblioteca `ibase_` que retorne o número de linhas de um consulta.

Existem duas opções:

- a primeira via SQL é executar a mesma consulta com um `count()`.
- A segunda via PHP é criar uma variável que armazene o número de linhas, algo como:

--

```
$totalLinhas = 0;
if($sth){
   while ($row = ibase_fetch_row($sth)) {
      echo $row[0], "\n";
      $totalLinhas++;
   }
   echo "total: ". $totalLinhas;
}
```

Comment: Muuito obrigado! Deu certo. Agora preciso organizar os dados que vem em tabela. Se possível poderia me ajudar ? Pois o nao estou conseguindo exibir informações do php dentro do html, mesmo usando a tag <?php ?>

Comment: @ProgMen, a primeira linha é fixa pois é o cabeçalho, dentro do while coloque algo como `<tr><td>valor1</td><td>valor2</td></tr>` para cada coluna retornado vai um par `<td></td>`

Comment: Correto. Vou tentar criar aqui, o problema era pra fazer esses dados aparecerem no html msm. Mas qualquer coisa crio outra pergunta, ja me ajudou mto. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

// contagem de linhas recebedas no array
$total = ibase_num_rows($sth);

// faz o loop no array, montando as linhas da tabela.
// Basta imprimir a variável

```
while($row = ibase_fetch_object($sth))
{
  $linhas = '<tr><td>Clientes: '. $row->NOME .'</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Diego, ibase nao tem essa função, ja tinha tentado. Obrigado.

Comment: Certo, não sou familiarizado com o ibase, mais em todo caso, você pode no sql fazer um count(NOME) as total, por exemplo antes. Para obter este retorno.

Comment: Sim, perfeitamente. E eu estava um pouco equivocado, consegui fazer sem a necessidade de contar as linhas. haha vlw